# What is the relationship between VS2008 Class Designer and Entity Framework Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I'm learning Entity Framework and have noticed that its Designer looks a lot like the Visual Studio Class Designer but doesn't seem to use it in any way, in fact these seem to be two approaches which solve a similar problem in different ways.

Am I missing something here or can these two tools be used together in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two tools use the same common VS implementation for diagrams (the DSL tools also use it). Hence a common look and feel.

Both specify classes, and allow members to be edited. However beyond that they are very different, class diagrams just generate code, but entity designer also manages mapping and ORM back end.

Comment: It just seems natural that the two belong together in one tool. I suppose there is going to be some integration coming here in VS2010?

Comment: They're two completely different technologies. Why combine them into one tool that does two different things instead of two tools that are each designed to facilitate their exact uses?